# When script is run, page open with an error that says address is not valid

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation

When i run script in eclipse, it first opens the tab in firefox that says "Address is not valid" and then it opens the url of the site i mentioned in my script. Please tell me about that error why does it happen?
see the attached screenshot.[image shows the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rende.png)

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @testuser  baseUrl = `"accounts.google.com";;` shows double ;; at the end.
Try your solution by using single ;

Comment: its mistakenly posted in the comment. tried using with single. but getting same error

Comment: I think ur jars are not updated

Comment: also base URL missing http://

Comment: how can i update the jar files?

Comment: Download it from seleniumhq and add it to add external jars

Comment: i am having the latest one.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will solve your problem

```
public class TestTestCaseEX {
WebDriver driver;


@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe"); //give your firefox driver path
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     String baseURL="https://accounts.google.com"
     driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}



 @Testclass)
    public void testing() throws InterruptedException {

    } 



@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {

    driver.close();
}

 }
```

Comment: I edited my answer you can try it again and set gecko Driver path and download driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Selenium_FF\\geckodriver.exe"); 
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 String baseURL="https://stackoverflow.com/";
 driver.get(baseURL);
```